# Google Sheets - I would like to make a way when ever a person presses a tick box the column to right automatically provides the user's name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically this is for a project with multiple people using it. if cell A1 had a tick box i would like cell B1 to display the name of the person that clicked the tick box. i want the rang to be as long as the file and works if more rows are added.

i was trying something like this. But i don't want their email instead have the user's name but if its possible with email that would work as well.

```
function setActiveUser() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // GET EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);

  //SET CELL A1 TO EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(email);
  for (var i = 0; i = true; i++) { //For loop to continue grabbing data until there's no more 
      
    }
}
```